# what is the expected exception in this code? C#

Tags: c#

[image: Is this NullReferenceException?]

```cs
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1{
    class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void PrintName(Player p)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            PrintName(player);
        }
    }
}
```

Hello, I'm trying to solve this question but I found that if I get `Name` value before setting its value, I will get `null` value, but it's not an exception.
Is the answer to this question `NullReferenceException`?

Thanks for you all guys :)

Comment: `p` might be `null`

Comment: how? can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, trying to read property p.Name on p == null will generate a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Try it : `Player foo; PrintName(foo);`

Comment: now, i understand, thanks alot

Comment: The code shown in the question won't provide any exception, because it won't compile. `Player` class is private and `PrintName()` is public. This will provide a *"Inconsistent accessibility"* error

Comment: @Cid actually, `Player` class is `internal` and so is `Main` class, so the code will compile..."Classes and structs declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that aren't nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question clearly asks what type of exception **might** occur. That way of phrasing implies that there are different ways the method `PrintName` might be utilized. And one of the ways is to pass null into `p`.

So basically your task is to assume all possible use cases of the method and determine what exceptions could be in each case. And you guessed right — it's `NullReferenceException`.

The idea behind exceptions is to show that program is in a state that it does not know how to continue work or that continuation will cause severe issues. So programmers should always check data (in your case — input params) to verify that particular method can work with input, otherwise the calling side should be notified about errors and work should be stopped — by throwing an exception, for example.

Comment: @MohamedMarzouk you are welcome! Please don't forget to upvote or mark if an answer actually helps you.

Comment: i'm very sorry, i have less 15 reputation

Comment: @MohamedMarzouk that's not a problem, don't be!

Answer (score 2):

So, as other answers have mentioned, there is a potential `NullReferenceException` in this method - if the argument passed to it is a reference to `null`, that's the exception the run time will throw.

**What I want to address is this:**

> (b) Modify the above method to handle this specific exception

So - how should you modify the method?

Let's start with the wrong solution and work our way up:

The wrong solution would be to wrap the `Console.WriteLine` statement in a `try...catch`, and catching the `NullReferenceException`.
This is wrong because you really, really should avoid catching `NullReferenceException`s.
In fact, you should strive to write your code in such a way that a `NullReferenceException` will not be a possibility.
Basically, a `NullReferenceException` is (probably [the most common](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/) and easiest to overlook but still) - [a **boneheaded** exception:](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)

```
public static void PrintName(Player p)
{
    try
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    } 
    // Don't do that!
    catch(NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("player is null!");
    }
}
```

---

A better solution (though probably not in this case) would be to validate your input, and throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the `p` argument is null. (btw, terrible name for an argument, but that's a different story).
This way, you wont get a null reference exception but an `ArgumentNullException` - which is a "valid" exception to catch - however, this is useful when writing public APIs, when you don't know in advance who will use your code and how.
Clearly, this is not the case here, and that would also quality as a boneheaded exception (or at least a vexing exception):

```
public static void PrintName(Player p)
{
    // Better, but still a bad option in this case.
    if(p is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(p));

    System.Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
```

---

You could check if the reference is not null and only then call `Console.WriteLine` - and that's a slightly better solution (Don't worry, will get there soon) - but then, how will your user know that the player is null? that gives no indication - simply nothing happens if `p` is null (Bonus reading: [The perfect non-null test](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/11/13/the-perfect-non-null-test/)):

```
public static void PrintName(Player p)
{
    // This is closer - but how would the user know that p is null?
    if(p is object) 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }
}
```

---

IMHO, the best course of action here is to use a combination of the [null conditional operator (?.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) and the [null coalescing operator (??)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

```
public static void PrintName(Player p)
{
    // This is probably the best solution in this case.
    System.Console.WriteLine(p?.Name ?? "player is null!");
}
```

This way, if `p` is null, you'll print out `"player is null!"`, so you avoid the possible `NullReferenceException`, and your code is still only a single line.

Comment: _however, this is useful when writing public APIs, when you don't know in advance who will use your code and how_: why the same technique isn't recommended for other scenarios? If you know that you will use your own library, why not throw an exception if you passed null there accidental? What's the difference?

Comment: _// This is probably the best solution in this case._: doing so you decided behaviour of the method based on what thoughts? I mean, why you decided that the method should output `player is null`? Initial code doesn't say anything that this logic is correct.

Comment: @cassandrad: Throwing an `ArgumentNullException` is great when you don't control who is using the code. You validate your input and you document that your method might throw exceptions and under what conditions. However, when writing a private method, or even an internal method - I personally think that's the wrong thing to do - since you control not only the method itself but also the code that's calling it - you better not call the method before you've made sure all the arguments are valid. After all, you don't want to rely on `try...catch` to check that the player is not null, do you?

Comment: @cassandrad As to your second comment - I made a judgment call. I figured you better show the user something instead of nothing. In my experience (both as a developer and more importantly - as a user) that's usually better. Initial code and question doesn't say much because it's an exercise - I gave an answer that IMHO will also be good for real-world situations.

Comment: `PrintName` isn't private, so it should be ok to throw, following your logic, am I missing something?

Comment: What if “player is null!” is a valid username, how to distinguish between two situations when `p` is null and it isn't?

Comment: 1. The method is public, the class itself is internal. 2. This is an example. You don't need to take it verbatim. I'll bet there's no kid named `Robert'; Drop tables students;--` either...

Comment: The point of my answer was to show different ways of handling this situations and say what I think the OP should do. You don't have to agree with me.

Comment: The point of my questions in comments is to show that your answer could be improved and I want to show where it could be done. And actually I +1'd your answer for covering the rest of OP's question, so I welcomed your effort from the beginning.

Comment: @cassandrad Well, feel free to edit into your own answer what you think my answer should have been... I still stand by what I wrote, but everybody has the right to their own opnion.

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

> A NullReferenceException exception is thrown when you try to access a
>   member on a type whose value is null.

In your case, if you pass null instead of instance of `Player` class, you will get `NullReferenceException` exception.

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1{
    class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void PrintName(Player p)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(p.Name);  //This line will throw null exception at run time, because p is null
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintName(null); // Possible way to get NullReferenceException
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is a runtime exception. The compiler can't throw that. The run time does.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, my bad I fixed it